# prevent button from overlapping text

Tags: java, android-studio, button, text, overlap

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textSize="100dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

[picture of code on phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAu5f.png)

The button overlaps the text. What can I do so when I press the button the text moves in front of the button and vice versa?

Comment: Can you use button.setVisibilty(View.gone) and button.setVisibilty(View.visible)?

Comment: I can do that, but I wanted to do that as a last resort. I want to prevent buttons from overlapping everything. But if I have to, I can make it disappear.